# Complex mapping of array to object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, dictionary

I have an array of strings:

```
["username", "String", "password", "String"]
```

And I want to convert this array to a list of Field objects:

```
class Field
    attr_reader :name, :type
    def initialize(name, type)
        @name = name
        @type = type
    end
end
```

So I need to map "username", "String" => Field.new("username", "String") and so on. The length of the array will always be a multiple of two.

Does anyone know if this is possible using a map style method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.8.6:

```
require 'enumerator'
result = []
arr = ["username", "String", "password", "String"]
arr.each_slice(2) {|name, type| result << Field.new(name, type) }
```

Or Magnar's solution which is a bit shorter.

For 1.8.7+ you can do:

```
arr.each_slice(2).map {|name, type| Field.new(name, type) }
```

Comment: Excellent that's what I'm looking for. I'm choosing this as the answer as it is more scalable that the Hash method for mapping multiple items to an object.

Answer (score 4):

A bracketed Hash call does exactly what you need. Given

```
a = ["username", "String", "password", "String"]
```

Then:

```
fields = Hash[*a].map { |name, type| Field.new name, type }
```

Comment: Thanks Magnar, an interesting solution that I didn't know existed. I'm going to go with sepp2k's answer as it is more generic. As far as I can see this will only handle the case where there is two object mapping to one, or am I wrong? Could you map say four strings to one object using this method?

Comment: The Hash-bracket constructor creates a hash of key=>value pairs out of every other value in the array. So it's perfect for your example, but no, it won't work for larger constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`each_slice`](http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M003107&name=each_slice).  It should do what you need.

Comment: 1.9 only, FWIW. Too bad there isn't a map_slice, which is what he's really after.

Comment: Maybe 1.8.7 too, I'm not sure.

Comment: each_slice is in 1.8.6 too, if you `require 'enumerator'` (stdlib)

Comment: It's 1.8.6.  Definitely not 1.9, the docs I linked are for 1.8.7