# Convert string to instance variables

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have an array `["agreement", "user", "client"]`. Is there any way to convert its items into objects `@agreement`, `@user`, `@client`?

Comment: Similar question addressed on this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287648/complex-mapping-of-array-to-object-in-ruby

Comment: Do you have corresponding classes of those inside the Array ?

Comment: Could you clarify your subject more ?

Comment: *"convert items into objects"* - the items already are objects, more specific: instances of class `String`. How are these strings related to instance variables with the same name and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
["agreement", "user", "client"]
.map{|k| instance_variable_get("@#{k}")}
```

Comment: Note that for some contexts, we may want `instance_variable_set` instead of `instance_variable_get`.